# Is it possible to keep a Postgres database schema under source control using DataGrip?

Tags: postgresql, version-control, datagrip

With Microsoft SQL Server, there is a great schema comparison tool which lets you keep a database schema under source control and push changes in both directions (schema project to database and database to schema project) which can then be kept under source control. This made development very easy directly on the local database, push the changes to the source controlled project and then apply the changes to other environments when required by using the schema comparison tool to generate the updates from the diff.

Is there any way to do something similar to this with DataGrip for PostgreSQL? 
Including how to keep a database as schema files.

I've seen that there is VCS integration but I can't get it to generate a project from a database and Google doesn't seem to help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, James

Answer (score 0):

There is no full integration for now. This is the ticket to follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3852

But you can now already generate you file-project for your database.

1. Select schema in the database explorer
2. `Context menu` -> `SQL scripts` -> `SQL Generator`
3. Choose the tab with the diskette, select options
4. Press `Save`.

[image]